# asyncio on django RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<future_timer() running got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

Task on asyncio running with command line on django. I have setup celery and celery is calling function to create loop on asyncio and it is calling to function which is having await of asyncio but it gives following error.

> yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
>   RuntimeError: Task > got Future  attached to a different loop.

I am running django with python3 on wsgi and celery on daemon process. Following is code example.

```
import asyncio
import datetime


@asyncio.coroutine
def slow_operation(name, sec):
    message = '%s started at %s' % (name, datetime.datetime.now())
    print(message)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(sec)
    return '%s ended at %s after %s seconds' % (name, datetime.datetime.now(), sec)


def got_result(future):
    print(future.result())


def run_process(name, sec):
    task = loop.create_task(slow_operation(name, sec))
    task.add_done_callback(got_result)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

i = [{'name': 'First Process', 'sec': 7},
     {'name': 'Second Process', 'sec': 3},
     {'name': 'Third Process', 'sec': 10},
     {'name': 'Fourth Process', 'sec': 2},
     {'name': 'Fifth Process', 'sec': 2}]

for val in i:
    run_process(val['name'], val['sec'])

loop.run_forever()
```

Here i am calling following part from different function as follow.

```
def create_asyncio_future_tasks():

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    i = [{'name': 'First Process', 'sec': 7},
         {'name': 'Second Process', 'sec': 3},
         {'name': 'Third Process', 'sec': 10},
         {'name': 'Fourth Process', 'sec': 2},
         {'name': 'Fifth Process', 'sec': 2}]

    for val in i:
        run_process(val['name'], val['sec'])

    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? How?